# How to convert a console application to a dll and vice versa in monodevelop on linux

Tags: c#, monodevelop

I want to write a library to practice my programming in general. So what I've been doing is to create a console app so that I can see its output but how do i turn this into a dll? Do note im running linux and using monodevelop. I cant seem to find anything online. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Open the Project Options:

`Project Options` -> `Build` -> `General`

Under `Code Generation`, change the `Compile Target` to **`Library`**

[image]